# Two equations and a question related to a well-known conjecture from number theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

On the Wikipedia page, the Beal´s conjecture is stated as:

> If $A^x+B^y=C^z$, where $A,B,C,x,y,z$ are positive integers with $x,y,z>2$, then $A$,$B$, and $C$ have a common prime factor.

I think that it is within reach (possibly, this is already solved somewhere) to rephrase the conjecture so as to have $A,B,C,x,y,z >2$ as the assumption.

To clarify, the case when $A=1$ or $B=1$ is already solved and some of us call it [Mihăilescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).

The case $C=1$ clearly does not have solutions.

So, the possible rephrasal needs for these cases to be considered and solved:

1) $2^x+B^y=C^z$

2) $A^x+2^y=C^z$

3) $A^x+B^y=2^z$

Of course, 1) and 2) can be considered as exactly the same cases, without any loss of generality.

So I am interested slightly in finding all of the solutions of two not extremely general Diophantine equations, the first task being:

> Find all solutions of the equation $2^x+B^y=C^z$ where $B,C,x,y,z \in \mathbb N$ and $x,y,z>2$

and the second one being:

> Find all solutions of the equation $A^x+B^y=2^z$ where $A,B,x,y,z \in \mathbb N$ and $x,y,z>2$

I know about [Fermat–Catalan conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%E2%80%93Catalan_conjecture) but this question is different, although much related.

> So I would like to know are these two tasks somewhere solved and, if they are not, what is, approximately, the current progress made so far on them?

Comment: The cases already solved are when you fix (some of) the exponents to some "small numbers". The problem then reduces to find all rational points of some algebraic curves.

Comment: @Xarles How large are those "small numbers", generally, "allowed" to be?

Comment: You can see in wikipedia page: between 2 and 5, mainly. Other cases are may be known. I don't know if someone has considered fixing one of the basis to 2 (but I am sure someone did, not if they succeeded proving something).

Comment: It is not even known, with current technology, that your equation 1) with $x=1$ has finitely many solutions $(B,C,y,z)$.

Comment: @MikeBennett I tried to solve that case, but some difficulties emerged, I think that there are no solutions.